# Problema con migración de paquetes de integration services

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, ssis

No sé si alguien podría por favor ayudarme un poco con este problema. No sé si será posible realizarlo. Pero me encuentro que necesito migrar unos proyectos de Integration Services de un servidor de SQL Server 2008 a otro servidor que es SQL Server 2016. No dispongo de los proyectos de Visual Studio de esos proyectos, solamente dispongo de la base de datos SSISDB en el servidor de SQL Server 2008.

¿Hay alguna manera de extraer los paquetes dtsx de la instalación realizada en el servidor SQL Server 2008 o sin el proyecto de Visual Studio no podré migrarlos teniendo que crear y picarme todos los proyectos desde cero?

Cualquier ayuda, me servirá. Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sugiero revisar el siguiente artículo en el blog Microsoft-SSIS:

[Get packages from SSIS Catalog](http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2016/04/get-packages-from-ssis-catalog.html)

En su momento me ayudó a extraer lo requerido para tener los programas en el Visual Studio y mediante SQL Server Data Tools proceder a ajustar desde una versión 2012 hacia una versión 2016.

Ten presente que no es un método directo y puede que algunos componentes, recuerdo los que tenían Scripting, haya que revisar y ajustar. Pero de pronto, como me sucedió a mi, te puede ser de ayuda.